# Why my onClick isn't playing with my public void?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I actually have the problem  [My Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGjRw.png)
When I click on the button "Jouer" (Play), it doesn't play the AudioSource
this is my void , how I can add another OnClick actions ?

```
public void Play()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1");
}
```

How can I add another action in `public void Play()`?
Because it doesn't play the audio source
I'm working with unity 3D

Comment: Well your method loads another scene ... so the current scene is unloaded and the audio source along with it ....

Comment: yes thanks , but now I create another element named AUDIO , into it there is AUDIOSOURCE COMPONENT but i can't drag into my previous Scene because the component is on another Scene . What i have to do ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you should insert AudioSource.Play() in your function

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html

in this way

```
    public void Play()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene1");

    yourAudioSource.Play();
}
```

or if the audio source is in another scene you can just use play on start

Comment: Thanks you a lot specimen 55 !

Comment: @Swyzax If this solved your problem, please accept it as the answer